# Primitive of $ \exp(-a \times x- \frac bx)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to calculate the primitive of $\exp\left(-a\times x-\frac bx\right)$

ie. $\int_0^c \exp\left(-ax-\frac bx\right)$

I found only [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343685/how-to-integrate-fx-exp-ax-b-x)

It is for $c=+\infty$

Comment: It is not a duplicate the first post is valid for integral from 0 to \infty here the bounds are 0 to c

Comment: There is no closed-form expression.

Comment: Only a fast convergent sum: $\int_0^c \exp \left(-a x-\frac{b}{x}\right) \, dx=b \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-a b)^k \Gamma \left(-1-k,\frac{b}{c}\right)}{\Gamma (1+k)}$

Comment: Many thanks Mariusz I was trying to use incomplete gamma function but how to compute it in Matlab since -1-k is negative

Comment: For incomplete gamma function with negative a we can use https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29321-evaluation-of-the-upper-incomplete-gamma-function

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^ce^{-ax-\frac{b}{x}}~dx$

$=\int_0^1e^{-acx-\frac{b}{cx}}~d(cx)$

$=c\int_0^1e^{-acx-\frac{b}{cx}}~dx$

$=c\int_\infty^1e^{-\frac{ac}{x}-\frac{bx}{c}}~d\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

$=c\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{bx}{c}-\frac{ac}{x}}}{x^2}~dx$

$=cK_1\left(\dfrac{b}{c},ac\right)$ (according to https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81935301.pdf)