# How to Integrate f(x)=1/(cx+d)*exp(-ax-b/x)

Tags: integration

I want to know if we can compute the integral_0^+\infty of f(x)=1/(cx+d)*exp(-ax-b/x). a>0, b>0 c>0, d>0.

I found only the integral from 0 to +\infty of exp(-ax-b/x)

[How to integrate $f(x) =\exp(-ax-b/x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343685/how-to-integrate-fx-exp-ax-b-x).
Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{cx+d}e^{-ax-\frac{b}{x}}dx$$?

Comment: Yes It  is correct

Comment: A solution in the known elementary functions is impossible